# Can't submit a post request to my /signup route

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

im learning how to setup a user sign up registration using node, but for some reason, whenever i send a POST request with email and password i receive a 404 error from Postman, saying that "Cannot POST /signup". i tried debugging my code, but it isn't visible to my eyes why is that happening.

Here's how i setup my user.

user model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    email: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        unique: true, 
        match: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/
    },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

user route

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const User = require("../models/user");

router.post("/signup", (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ email: req.body.email })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.length >= 1) {
        return res.status(409).json({
          message: "Mail exists"
        });
      } else {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
              error: err
            });
          } else {
            const user = new User({
              _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
              email: req.body.email,
              password: hash
            });
            user
              .save()
              .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                res.status(201).json({
                  message: "User created"
                });
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).json({
                  error: err
                });
              });
          }
        });
      }
    });
});

router.delete("/:userId", (req, res, next) => {
  User.remove({ _id: req.params.userId })
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "User deleted"
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/product');
const orderRoutes = require('./api/routes/order');
const userRoutes = require('./api/routes/user');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:' +process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW+'@cluster0-shard-00-00-xykap.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-xykap.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-xykap.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});


app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use('/uploads',express.static('uploads'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
 });
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error: {
            message: error.message
        }
    });
});
app.use('/products', productRoutes);
app.use('/orders', orderRoutes);
app.use ('/users', userRoutes);
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Have you tried to post to "/users/signup"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your signup view is in the `userRoutes` file, its path will be prefixed with `'/users'` because of the line `app.use ('/users', userRoutes);`.

Thus the full path for your sign up view is `'/users/signup'`, rather than just `'/signup'` on its own.

Answer (score 1):

`app.use ('/users', userRoutes);` it will generate `/users/signup` route, so you should change to `app.use(userRoutes)`